# Codeigniter class extends

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, extends

I have problem with extend custom class in last CodeIgniter version.

in folder libraries i have two (class) files:
 - B.php
 - C.php

B.php code

```
class B
{
  public $anything;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->anything = true;
  }
}
```

C.php code

```
class C extends B {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

And now, if i run controller where i have **$this->load->library("C");** page has error

> Fatal error: Class 'B' not found in
>   F:\UwAmp\www\backend\application\libraries\C.php on line 2

I don't know where is problem. Can you help me?

Comment: You will have to load `class B`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load both B and C otherwise PHP/CodeIgniter doesn't know about B.

Comment: True! I thought that is automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

include your base class into sub class

in C.php add

```
include 'path_to_B.php'
```

Comment: CodeIgniter has its own way of loading code that is name based.

Comment: @idstam this will also work ryt? But we should load B and then load C? I'm new to CI.

Comment: This is the PHP way of loading code so it will work in CI, but the CI framework won't know that you have the code loaded.